# Undefined symbols, though they are defined in our .cpp file

Tags: c++, g++, ld

I am working on getting a library to build in linux. This builds and works in Windows, but on Linux I am getting an unresolved symbol in our library when consuming the static lib. The code appears as follows:

```
class MyClass : public AnotherClassRefCounded
{
public:
  static bool queryInstance(MyClass **ppmyClass);
};
```

Inside the .cpp file for this class I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass* MyClass::m_pInstance = NULL;

bool MyClass::queryInstance(MyClass **myClass)
{
  if(m_pInstance == NULL)
  {
    m_pInstance = new MyClass();
    m_pInstance->incRef(); 
  }

  m_pInstance->incRef();
  *myClass = m_pInstance;
  return true;
}
```

Now when running `nm -Cu` on libMyLib.a I get the following output:

```
[matt6809@hogganz400 libDebug]$ nm -Cu libMappingd.a | grep queryInstance
                 U AFewMoreScopes::MyClass::queryInstance(AFewMoreScopes::MyClass**)
```

My system info is:

```
[matt6809@hogganz400 libDebug]$ cat /etc/redhat-release ; gcc --version
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
gcc (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

For copyright reasons I cannot post the identical code. I have reproduced the code to the best of my abilities. If you feel I am missing any info please don't hesitate to ask for it.

---

**UPDATE**

Example of build:

...

```
g++ -c -include Mappingd -pipe -w -g -fPIC -Wall -W <DEFINE FLAGS> <INCLUDE FLAGS> -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp
```

...

```
ar cqs libMappingd.a <all object files>
```

---

**UPDATE 0**

This is very interesting. Inside the object file for "MyClass" the symbol is not undefied:

```
MyClass.o:
                 <My Symbol Not Undefined>
```

However if you go to another one of the object files:

```
<Other Object>.o:
                 ...
                 U Scope::MyClass::queryInstance(Socpe::MyClass**)
```

---

**UPDATE1**

```
g++ -c -include Mappingd -pipe -w -g -fPIC -Wall -W -DLINUXx86 <DEFINE FLAGS> <INCLUDE FLAGS> -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp
g++ -c -include Mappingd -pipe -w -g -fPIC -Wall -W -DLINUXx86 <DEFINE FLAGS> <INCLUDE FLAGS> -o OtherClass.o OtherClass.cpp
rm -f libMappingd.a
ar cqs libMappingd.a <Other Objects> MyClass.o OtherClass.o
```

and

```
g++ -c -include Mappingd -pipe -w -g -fPIC -Wall -W -DLINUXx86 <DEFINE FLAGS> <INCLUDE FLAGS> -o OtherClass.o OtherClass.cpp
g++ -c -include Mappingd -pipe -w -g -fPIC -Wall -W -DLINUXx86 <DEFINE FLAGS> <INCLUDE FLAGS> -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp
rm -f libMappingd.a
ar cqs libMappingd.a <Other Objects> OtherClass.o MyClass.o
```

Make no difference I still get undefined symbol in the other library.

Comment: How do you make `libMappingd.a`? Post commands and their output.

Comment: Why is 'MyClass' is changed into 'RuntimeEnvironment' in your cpp file ?

Comment: I am using Qt to build the static lib. Give me a sec to get a single line out of the compile statments.

Comment: Copyright reasons? I think this is fair use, but whatever. Do you get the same error with the code you've posted?

Comment: I have a singleton class that uses static Instance methods and attributes, and it compiles just fine in a library. I am fearfull there might be something wrong deeper in the Library we are building, just trying to see if there is a simple answer before I dig deeper.

Comment: If I inline the method I don't get the unresolved symbol

Comment: And what lies behind `AFewMoreScopes`? Some namespace or nested class?

Comment: Exactly what symbols are undefined?

Comment: There are quite a few, I will give you the ones that are most closly related to the file. Let me rebuild, I inlined the function and that seems to have fixed the problem. But it is not a desired solution.

Comment: Re: Update0 - why do you think this is interesting? Have you tried to declare it with `extern` keyword in OtherObject? BTW libraries are one of the reasons why singletons are better than static methods. With global static fields you will also have other kinds of troubles when dealing with dynamically loaded libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I discovered that the archiver on RHEL 6.1 has a bug in it. I stopped trying to pull in the static libs directly into the shared dynamic library, and instead I unpacked the static libs, and pulled the corresponding object files directly into the .so file. I now have 0 undefined symbols in our library apart from the ones that I am not statically linking against.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference I know between VC++ and GCC is that the order of the object files you give the linker matters. A symbol which is used in object file A, must be defined either in it or after it in the link order.

Try moving MyClass.o to the end of the object files list.

Comment: I thought that ar just pulled in all symbols without checking?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan - I'm actually not sure if the archiver depends on order... I was talking about the linker, since you said that you get the error when **consuming** the static library, meaning when using the linker. Do you use this undefined symbol elsewhere in the final executable/shared lib? If so, try moving libMappingd.a later in the list, and let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: Both the files that are having issues with the undefined symbol are in Mapping, and Mapping is dependent on all the other libraries. Thus it is listed first. Copying from the Qt Project file "LIBS += \
        -lMapping \
        <ALL other libs>"